# How to convert this code using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following classes :

```
Class A {
List<B> b
 //getters and setters
   }
  CLass B {
   List<C> c
 //getters and setters
}
  Class C {}
```

Now i have a list :

```
List<List<A>> listA;
```

What i want to do is remove an element of type A from the inner lists of listA if every element of `List<B>` has an empty `List<C>`. I have done this using Iterators but now i have to do it using streams. The following code works using iterators :

```
Iterator<List<A>> iterator1 = listA.iterator();
      while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
          Iterator<A> iterator2 = iterator1.next().iterator();
          while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
              List<B> listB =iterator2.next().getB();
              Iterator<B> iterator3 = listB.iterator();
              int i=0;
              while(iterator3.hasNext()) {
                  if(iterator3.next().getC().size() != 0) {
                      continue;
                  }
                  else {
                      i++;
                      if(i == list.size()) {
                          iterator2.remove();
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Can someone help me convert this into streams??

Comment: Any efforts made so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can process a stream on inner lists and then filter `A` elements based on the data in their `b` fields:

```
List<List<A>> selected = 
       listA.parallelStream()
            .map(aList -> aList.stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.getB()
                                  .stream()
                                  .anyMatch(b -> !b.getC().isEmpty()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To remove from the same list instances, you can just run an index-based iteration over the main list, then explicitly remove from inner lists items that match the criteria:

```
IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
    .forEach(
      i -> listA.get(i)
        .removeAll(
          listA.get(i)
            .stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getB().stream().allMatch(b -> b.getC().size() == 0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())) );
```

This last snippet is just compiling a `List<A>` (that somehow contains an empty `List<C>` in the tree) to be removed from corresponding entries in the main list.

Comment: Hi Ernest, is there any workaround for only to remove these elements from the list and not to return a ffiltered list?

Comment: please don't use `parallelStream` unless you know that you're working with horribly big data

Comment: @Lino Thanks for the observation. But "horribly big" doesn't give a clear indication (even though that gives an idea), could you perhaps give a more precise guideline?

Comment: Ernest, thanks for the answer. I think it must be allMatch instead of anyMatch

Comment: @Nana I think you're right, because you're skipping an iteration if `getC().size() == 0` is false anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should not try "remove" with stream. Stream is designed to be stateless, and the variables should be immutable. Stream can be used to go through your lists, and collect values you want to keep into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

> What i want to do is remove an element of type A from the inner lists of listA if every element of List has an empty List. I have done this using Iterators but now i have to do it using streams

You can achieve this quite easy with a single `filter()` pipeline:

```
List<A> cleanedList = listA.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getListB().stream().map(B::getListC).noneMatch(List::isEmpty))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```